# Port-forwarding for the pod in GKE private cluster with NO global control plane access

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We have our pods running in GKE private cluster with NO global control plane access. We have one bastion host which is used to connect to this private cluster and kubectl apis can be accessed from there.

user --> bastion (kubectl and authorised to use cluster) -->GKE private cluster

One issue in this architecture is, we need to port-forward to the app pods in the private cluster, however as the bastion host is different than our localhost (VM where browser), we can not access the apps with port-forward. For the same reason, forwarding is not working from Gcloud shell as well.

Do we have any suggestions from GKE for port-forwarding use cases in private cluster paradigm. We do not want to provision RDP instance and add that to authorised network just for port forwarding use case.

we have refereed to the doc , but did not get info on this.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing port forwarding on **GCP console** you can do the web preview port-forward there also.

Use the **web preview** option when you are trying the port-forwarding from the console.

It will redirect you to a web preview and show you output on port that you are forwarding.

[image]

Read more at : https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview

Comment: No, in this case we are connecting to GKE from bastion host, it does not connect from cloud shell as well,we have to login from bastion. So, port-forwading from console is also not an option here as it first connect to cluster using cloud shell where it just hangs..:(

Comment: Did you try adding gcloud shell's IP to authorised networks of your gke private cluster so that you can access the cluster through gcloud shell?